# I want to check how many pdfs in a folder with Powershell with a function

Tags: powershell

I want to check how many pdf files a folder. For example in my C:\Temp\Test folder there are 6 pdf files and 6 txt files.

```
PS H:\> dir c:\temp\test


    Directory: C:\temp\test


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                                                                         
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                                                                         
-a----        21/01/2022  10:05 PM            611 1.pdf                                                                                                                                                                        
-a----        26/01/2022   5:22 PM              0 1.txt                                                                                                                                                                        
-a----        22/01/2022  12:19 PM           3939 2.pdf                                                                                                                                                                        
-a----        26/01/2022   5:22 PM              0 2.txt                                                                                                                                                                        
-a----        08/01/2022   4:53 PM          27992 3.pdf                                                                                                                                                                        
-a----        26/01/2022   5:22 PM              0 3.txt                                                                                                                                                                        
-a----        08/01/2022   4:53 PM          27992 4.pdf                                                                                                                                                                        
-a----        26/01/2022   5:22 PM              0 4.txt                                                                                                                                                                        
-a----        22/01/2022  12:19 PM           3939 5.pdf                                                                                                                                                                        
-a----        26/01/2022   5:22 PM              0 5.txt                                                                                                                                                                        
-a----        21/01/2022  10:05 PM            611 6.pdf
```

If I use following PS, I got the right result 6

```
PS H:\> $directoryInfo = Get-ChildItem C:\Temp\Test | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq ".pdf"}
$file_count = $directoryInfo.count
$file_count
6
```

However, when I use it like a function and deleted 2 pdfs in the folder. It still show as 6 pdfs. While, the $file_count in the function show as 4.

```
PS H:\> function CheckFileCount($Folder) {
$directoryInfo = Get-ChildItem $Folder | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq ".pdf"}
$file_count = $directoryInfo.count
return $file_count
}

dir C:\Temp\Test
CheckFileCount C:\Temp\Test
Write-Host "There are $file_count PDFs in this folder."


    Directory: C:\Temp\Test


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                                                                         
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                                                                         
-a----        26/01/2022   5:22 PM              0 1.txt                                                                                                                                                                        
-a----        26/01/2022   5:22 PM              0 2.txt                                                                                                                                                                        
-a----        08/01/2022   4:53 PM          27992 3.pdf                                                                                                                                                                        
-a----        26/01/2022   5:22 PM              0 3.txt                                                                                                                                                                        
-a----        08/01/2022   4:53 PM          27992 4.pdf                                                                                                                                                                        
-a----        26/01/2022   5:22 PM              0 4.txt                                                                                                                                                                        
-a----        22/01/2022  12:19 PM           3939 5.pdf                                                                                                                                                                        
-a----        26/01/2022   5:22 PM              0 5.txt                                                                                                                                                                        
-a----        21/01/2022  10:05 PM            611 6.pdf                                                                                                                                                                        
4
There are 6 PDFs in this folder.
```

It looks like the function can't return $file_count value. What's wrong here? Thank you in advance.

Thank you all and I think its been solved.

Comment: You need to assign the output of the function to the variable: `$file_count = CheckFileCount C:\Temp\Test`. Or use a different [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes), but I do not recommend that.

Comment: Thanks iRon.  It works after I assign the output. Thank you again.

Comment: @AlexYou - the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet has two parameters that you likely otta use. the first = `-File` to get only files. the 2nd is `-Filter` with a value of `*.pdf` to get only pdf files. doing that will speed things up since you will let the _filesystem_ do the work instead of grabbing everything and _then_ filtering for what you want. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey That's pretty cool! `$directoryInfo = Get-ChildItem $Folder -File -Filter *.pdf`.  Bang! How simple it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AlexYou - you are most welcome! glad to have helped a little ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function worked for me flawlessly when calling the function only.

I am adding a really good article about scopes in PowerShell:
[PowerShellScopes](https://www.varonis.com/blog/powershell-variable-scope)

---

Your problem is:

> Write-Host "There are $file_count PDFs in this folder."

Try saving the function result to a var like so:

> $function_result = CheckFileCount 'C:\Software\example'

And then view the result:

> Write-Host "There are $function_result PDFs in this folder."